# Wpf Window "super class"

Tags: c#, wpf

Some 30 years ago, I developed a big app for fresh fruit packers. I followed a nice paradigm, taken from Informix-4GL: the same screen allows the user to set a "query by example" or to insert a new "record", or update one of them after a successfully one. It maintained a "current list" (the resulting query result and the new records added) wich could be navegated with PgUp and PgDwn Keys. Of course, all that stuff was expressed as mapped text.
The very important thing is that the screen was idle until the user did a "command" to start a new query, an insert or update (or even a delete) operation. 
Now, it's the time to evolve that app. 
I'm thinking in Wpf and its Preview* group of routed events, to catch the main user "command".
But because there are lots of screens (near one for every entity in the database) it's important to set what is common between them. 
Is it the best way (in Wpf) to set one or two "super classes" of Windows for this approach?
TIA

Comment: If the original app was in Informix-4gl and you are looking to "evolve that app", why not use some of the tools e.g. Genero and there are others, that will allow your app to evolve to modern day environments (GUI/Web/Mobile etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Technically — sure, you can create a class that inherits from System.Windows.Window, have all windows in your app inherit from that one, and implement some common logic in that class.

However, this approach is not considered a best practice for WPF and other XAML-based platforms. Your window and other GUI classes should only contain code specific to presentation. Your model classes that handle the DB queries should not depend on the exact GUI you’re using to present these models.

While not required, a third-party MVVM library is helpful to e.g. provide design-time models for the IDE. As for the specific library, lately I prefer Caliburn Micro, before that I had positive experience with MVVM Light.

With MVVM, it’s fine to have a base model class with some logic that’s common across different model classes. In fact, many libraries encourage you to do so. They provide their own base classes for your models. Such as Screen or PropertyChangedBase from Caliburn Micro.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm trying Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: I'm getting crazy trying to compile the samples for Caliburn.Micro. It have plenty of c# 6.0 code which I don't have installed. Some of the expressions may be easily circumvented, but no others. I'thing I will be giving up.

Comment: Is this thing serious? To overcome the 6.0 limits, I downloaded the 2.02 version, which is previous to 6.0 release. The library compiled w/o complaint, but the first sample I take, has errors.

Comment: Finally, I tried MVVM Light and it seems the best for me.

Comment: @marcelo BTW when I started with XAML in ~2011 (it was WP7 Silverlight, but all XAML-based platforms are very close conceptually and technically, SL, WPF, WinRT, UWP), I also liked MVVM Light for its simplicity. Eventually I got myself comfortable with MVVM and databinding shenanigans, needed more features, so currently I prefer Caliburn.Micro for new projects.